# Implement Internal Interface in Tests

Tags: c#, testing, interface, mocking, internals

I have made `internal` classes and functions visible to my test project via:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute">
    <_Parameter1>MyProject.Tests</_Parameter1>
  </AssemblyAttribute>
</ItemGroup>
```

This works fine, but now I am trying to implement the following `internal` interface in my tests for mocking purposes:

```
internal interface IRepository
{
    void Function1();        
}
```

In my test code, I have implemented the above interface as follows:

```
internal class MockRepository : IRepository
{
    internal void Function1()
    {
        // Do something.
    }        
}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> 'MockRepository' does not implement interface member 'IRepository.Function1()'. 'MockRepository.Function1()' cannot implement an interface member because it is not public. [MyProject.Tests]

It seems that `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` only applies to classes and functions.

Do I really have to make my `internal` interface public to let tests mock it, or is there a way to keep it `internal`?

I ask because I want to keep as many things accessible only to my project and its tests.

Comment: Have you tried just making `Function1` in the mock public?

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks! The initial version of this comment wasn't very clear to me so I didn't really understand it. By the time I found the edited version, I already figured it out. Many thanks for helping though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out. Turns out all I needed to do was make the implementation itself `public`.

The mock class itself can stay `internal`:

```
internal class MockRepository : IRepository
{
    public void Function1()
    {
        // Do something.
    }        
}
```